# Unable to create a subscription: Error (type 11) indicates record type not found, even though it exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, cksubscription

I am trying to set up a Cloudkit subscription that sends me a notification, each time a new record of a certain record type is created.  The code I am using to setup subscription is below.

It is working on one device.  If I create a new record on another device, it gets the notification.

But the same code returns a Type 11 error when run on another device. This same device is able to create a record of this type and store it.

I am totally stumped.  Any pointers to what is going on and how to resolve it will be greatly appreciated!

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
    CKSubscription *artisSubscription = [[CKSubscription alloc]
                                         initWithRecordType:@"DummyRecordType"
                                         predicate:predicate
                                         options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation];

    CKNotificationInfo *notificationInfo = [CKNotificationInfo new];
    notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = @"how many dummies will I get.";
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = YES;

    artisSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo;

[self.publicDatabase saveSubscription:artisSubscription
               completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
                   if (error)
                   {
                       NSLog(@"error %@ while saving subscription %@",error,artisSubscription) ;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       NSLog(@"Successfully created subscription") ;
                   }
               }];
```

**This NSLog shows that the device is able to create a record of type DummyRecordType**

```
2016-03-20 01:41:40.654 Successfully stored dummy record record <CKRecord: 0x14f662e40; recordType=DummyRecordType, recordID=AF6F246A-9CBA-412C-8B7D-441E47105DC3:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=im0be2zp, values={
FirstName = "Sandra Boticelli";
```

}>

**This NSLog shows that the device is not able to create a subscription for this same record type DummyRecordType**

```
 2016-03-20 01:41:48.053 error <CKError 0x14f643e80: "Unknown Item" (11/2003); server message = "did not find required record type: _sub_trigger_sub_0e58a7f4546c28b9d6f073bfa910e7f3"; uuid = E5CA48C1-8D46-47DD-8D0F-C486C2DA7D5D; container ID = "iCloud.com.apm.smartiothome.DoodleSend"> while saving subscription <CKSubscription: 0x14f57a2e0; ; Query Subscription: recordType=DummyRecordType, predicate=TRUEPREDICATE, subscriptionOptions=1, subscriptionID=FA20F835-DFB5-418A-BB51-462432BD4EFE, zoneID=(null)>
```

Comment: I think it is a ios9 vs ios8 compatibility issue.  Since it works if both devices are on ios9 but not if one is on ios8.